# contenteditable change background color after edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a spreadsheet-like application and using a table `<td>` with a tag `contenteditable = "true"` and I want the background color of the cell to be changed after it was changed.

From my research I figured I would need javascript or jquery to do so, however I know very little of it. Where do I start? So far I have figured how to change color when the cell is *being* edited. thank you!

```
<td contenteditable="true" >
  <style>
     [contenteditable="true"]:focus {
       background-color: yellow;
     }
  </style>
  "Stuff"
</td>
```

Comment: Please check the example below.

Answer (score 1):

So I see you figured out how to change color when the cell is being edited. Now to change the cell *after* its done being edited you can use the following example.

jQuery has a function called [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) which triggers when the element loses focus from the user. It will then add the class `orange` which will change the background to orange.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("td").focusout(function(){
      $(this).addClass("orange");
  });
});
```

```css
td[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.orange{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <td contenteditable="true" >"Stuff"</td>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/8zbrxwpz/

Comment: btw why do you need a focusout here.

Comment: The `focusout` is my solution to OP wanting "the background color of the cell to be changed after it was changed." So by using `focusout` I am assuming the user is currently done editing the field when focus is lost and we can change the color like OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use `td[contenteditable="true"]` selector, and add the table parent as well.

```css
td[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <table>
  <td contenteditable="true" >"Stuff"</td>
  </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kasyzytr/